# Why something like this is invalid in php?

Tags: php

I was recently refactoring. And thought this would awesome. But is not allowed.

```html
<?php


function(){

  doSomething() && return true;
}
```

Comment: `return (bool) learnSomething();`

Comment: @tereško What are you trying to say by this `return (bool) learnSomething();` exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `return` is a statement and cannot be used as part of an expression. An expression is something that returns/results in a value. `return` doesn't result in any value, but operands to `&&` must result in a value for the `&&` expression to be evaluable.

Comment: Moreover, the logic depicted in the question doesn't actually make sense/is incomplete. What does the function return in the failure case?

Comment: It could be argued that it's supposed to be analogous to `if (doSomething) return true`. So, it wouldn't return anything otherwise.

Comment: Indeed, which is precisely why this is a bad idea ;-) otoh, I do wish that `throw` was a valid expression... `doStuff() or throw ...` and `$stuff ? $otherstuff : throw ...` and `$var ?? throw ...` are all things that I wish I could do

Comment: @DaveRandom . I am very sorry for being a beginner. This is the first q in so